# Typescript Generic Type with callback and args (wrapping pupeteer)

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I'm trying to make some wrapping function around puppeteer. But I'm struggling with TypeScript typings for that.

Basically, puppeteer allows injecting some code this way

`page.$eval("selector" ,(element, args) => {}, someArgs)`

I want to make one function that allows using the callback and passes the "someArgs". My selector remains the same.

Here is my attempt (also stackBlitz link below for detailed repro)

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const runForVideo = <T extends any[]>(
    cb: (video: HTMLVideoElement, ...args: [...T, ...undefined[]]) => void,
    ...args: T
  ) => page.$eval('video', (video, ...args) => cb(video, ...args), args); // ...args are yielding :'(
  // Argument of type '[FlattenHandle<T>]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[...T, ...undefined[]]'.
  // Source provides no match for variadic element at position 0 in target.(2345)

  await runForVideo((video, a) => {
    // a is undefined
  });
  await runForVideo((video, volume) => {
    video.volume = volume;
  }, 5);
  await runForVideo(
    (video, volume, text) => {
      video.volume = volume;
      console.log(text);
    },
    5,
    'hello'
  );
})();
```

I want that `runForVideo` 1st arg callback to have a second argument only if the runForVideo has an arg (or more) and have the same types.

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks

PS: I added a full example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zxyvaa?file=index.ts and you can see this works just `cb` is yielding that it need `FlattenHandle`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgM4ILYFMBilaIQA8AKgHwAUUARgFzIUBucAJlgvQBIkCyAMgDVW7AKIAbLNggwANMgCGAJwDmqeiQCUyALxlkjBKzlLVAJgD8ydRoDeN4MkfIA9M+QA5BAHcFK1Mjh-VHlsZBgATwAHLDCAC3kUE1RTBi9YuChYgP8ESPgkCHkxDQA6YABfcuBgdGw8aHyICiY5SK1dZHsnFzdItFiEMDEWZGoYiCxGLEVkBBnINhA4CZY5OeRIAGsIbxR1tPkYSem5ajAYZB2LrAAPQJh-ZbjA5Ch5VCwKjWqoJFQLyLvD4sACCKh0yAArDVMLh8I1moxWu09F0nK5kH0XhAwBgxjMKMFQhFogp-IDUMCwcpvuVWkCsKCVN9qhiRFMUOBFDBYtNgL8IP9MQymaoIQBtSEyABEvLEYgQ0oAujC6vDCIjWnJUCjOg50b1spdcfiGESYiSYu9hZTGdTxQAGJXfboYx5BGCKZbKM0hC1RK3kkX2gCMzoqchKUYpVOZwCAA

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8L3W) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining (but first you might want to fix the `passedArg` vs `passedArgs` typo and use a `const` assertion or something if you expect the compiler to keep track of the order and length of the `passedArgs` array). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: We progress in the good way, I still have one small error, I've added a full example to match the initial need https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zxyvaa?file=index.ts

Comment: (Was a typo) I've fixed the whole post and explained the need, Maybe you could help me on that :) Thanks (always impressed that you respond alltime on TS thread ahah)

Comment: I cannot help because I don't know anything at all about puppeteer, sorry.  If you can refactor to remove that dependency I'd be happy to look; otherwise hopefully someone else will come along with the necessary knowledge.

Comment: I understand that you don't look at puppeteer, but there the issue is that eval wrap all elements with `FlattenHandle` and so I get the following error with the code in the example (updated). This is a TS issue here having type mismatch

Argument of type '[FlattenHandle<T>]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[...T, ...undefined[]]'. Source provides no match for variadic element at position 0 in target.(2345)

Comment: I hope I was clear in my previous comment about my rules of engagement here; it's probably not fruitful for us to try to negotiate about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is that your callback type is not compatible with puppetter's callback type. puppeteer expects a type to be compatible with `string | EvaluateFuncWith<Element,V>`. If you change the signature of your function into this :

```
  const runForVideo = <T extends any[]>(
    cb: EvaluateFuncWith<HTMLVideoElement, [...T]>,
    ...args: T
  ) => page.$eval('video', cb, ...args);
```

it should work as expected.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-lshesu?file=index.ts)

Comment: It now works as expected! Thank you very much 